# Replace Null based on existing column value

Tags: pyspark

I am working on a dataframe. One of the column of dataframe for which there is NULL in some records. I need to replace NULL with some calculation over the exiting column.

eg.
[current dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd5VR.png)

required: -
[required dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25FhU.png)

Comment: can you provide the calculation details for replacing nulls .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your dataframe name is **df**.

Here is the code for your use case. It checks for the nullability of column B and applies a calculation to replace NULL. From your provided images of values what I could decipher is that the value of the calculation would be 500 + column C value (for actual case you can change this calculation as per your requirement).

```
CONSTANT = 500
new_column_2 = when(col("B").isNull(), (CONSTANT + col("C"))).otherwise(col("B"))
df.withColumn("B", new_column_2)
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pre-calculate the new value, you can use pyspark like below. It seems Spark doesn't support calculating the value from other columns dynamically.

```
data = [
[1,0.5,1],
[2,0.5,1],
[2,0.78,2],
[3,0.321,3],
[2,None,4],
[3,None,1],
[3,None,2]
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.fillna(500, subset=['B']).show()
```

If you can use pandas however, you should be able to do it this way.

```
pdf = df.toPandas()
pdf = pdf.fillna(value={'B': pdf.C + 500})
```

Of course, you can always convert the dataframe back to Spark:

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
df2.show()
```

**Update:**
After reading Gourav's answer, I realised it's possible with Spark. Don't forget to import necessary methods.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when
df.withColumn('B', when(col('B').isNull(), 500+col('C')).otherwise(col('B'))).show()
```